# Translate cluster to Bitmap Address

Tags: ntfs, clustered-index

I have a cluster number and I have a dump of the $Bitmap of my drive. I am having a hard time translating cluster number to $Bitmap offset. Cluster number is 16749682 in decimal and here is the screenshot of the $Bitmap file. I need to find this specific cluster to number to see if this is occupied or free. Any help will be appreciated. $Bitmap file shows me offsets and the maximum offset it gives me is 12B90. I am unable to convert cluster number in decimal to offset of $Bitmap
[image: Bitmap File Image]

Comment: Simply put, each bit in the `$Bitmap` corresponds to a cluster: https://whereismydata.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/forensics-what-is-the-bitmap/

Comment: so technically, my cluster number divided by 16 should work?

Comment: Why 16? If you are looking for the byte containing the bit of cluster 16749682 then you would do `16749682 / 8`. Then you will need to find the bit inside that byte, i.e. `16749682 % 8`. Of course all positions have to be counted starting from 0, in fact bit 2 is the third bit.

Comment: 16 because each row as shown in my screenshot above, shows F clusters. So, shouldn't I be dividing by F?

Comment: First of all, `0xF` is 15, not 16 so dividing "by F" doesn't make any sense. Secondly, that's just a representation used by your hex editor. That would be completely pointless when you implement the computation in your code. Each row is showing 16 bytes, each having 8 bits, so it's showing the bits corresponding to 128 clusters. Maybe, if you show your existing code it will be easier to check it. :)

Comment: thank you for correcting me there. But it's not a code. I am trying to find the cluster in bitmap and the way winHex is representing it, I divided it by 16 and not F, to find out whether the cluster for my deleted (shift deleted) file was available or still occupied but, either I'm still unable to correctly translate cluster value to offset here by dividing by 16 or it's something else

Comment: **This is a website about programming.** Besides, the bitmap is correctly updated when you delete a file. Instead of checking the bitmap, if you want to recover the file go for it and use a recovery program. :)

Comment: Which stackexchange would be suitable for such questions?

Comment: I guess SuperUser might be a good one.